# Notificaciones en Firebase no se borran cuando tienen que borrarse

Tags: java, android, firebase

Cuando le doy un like a un post el usuario tiene que recibir una notificación y veo que la notificación se agrega en Firebase. El problema es que si le doy un like a 5 posts distintos las notificaciones se agregan a Firebase, pero si luego los intento quitar solo se borra la notificación del último post y los demás no.

Puedo quitar y poner un like y las notificaciones se mandan, pero cuando los quito las notificaciones tienen que borrarse de Firebase pero solo se borra la notificación del último post. Los demás no...

Cómo puedo hacer que se borren todas las notificaciones de todos los posts si le quito el like?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**CommentAdapter**

```
holder.like.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (holder.like.getTag().equals("like")) {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes").child(post.getPostid()).child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(true);
                addLikeNotification(post.getPublisher(), post.getPostid());
            } else {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes").child(post.getPostid()).child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).removeValue();
                deleteNotification(post.getPublisher());
            }
        });

 private void deleteNotification(String userid) {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Notifications").child(userid);
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Notification notification = snapshot.getValue(Notification.class);
                    if (notification != null) {
                        reference.child(notification.getNotificationId()).removeValue();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void addLikeNotification(final String userid, final String postid) {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Notifications").child(userid);

        String notificationId = reference.push().getKey();

        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("userid", mFirebaseUser.getUid());
        hashMap.put("comment", "liked your event");
        hashMap.put("postid", postid);
        hashMap.put("notificationId", notificationId);
        hashMap.put("ispost", true);

        reference.child(notificationId).setValue(hashMap);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que deberias hacer en este caso es no usar el cliente para borrar y enviar notificaciones pero deberias usar Cloud Functions, con cloud functions te aseguras que cada vez que ocurre un cambio sobre los datos que maneja tus notificaciones puedas borrarlos

Acá tenes un ejemplo

https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications

Y acá tenes los triggers que podes usar

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events

Si lo haces desde el cliente podes generar inconsistencias en los datos de la notificacion por que no estas utilizando una transaccion atomica por cada vez que borras o agregas

Con respecto a tu pregunta, el problema esta en `.child(notifid)` en el else cuando tratas de borrar la notificación, seguramente anteriormente seteas el valor de `notifid` como la ultima notificacion que se agrega, entonces al borrarla borras la ultima , osea el ultimo valor de `notifid`, lo que deberias hacer es hacer una query que encuentre la notificacion que buscas, encontrar el `notifid` correspondiente a la notificacion que queres borrar, obtener ese `notifid` y luego borrar la notificacion.

Te recomiendo usar el debugger, poner un punto de debug en ese `.removeValue` y ver el valor de `notifid`, si el valor coinside con el ultimo valor de tus notificaciones es por que `notifid` se actualiza cada vez que se agrega una nueva notificacion y no esta obteniendo el id de la notificacion que queres borrar.

### Edit

Lo que deberias borrar es el valor del notifiid que clicas y no del de que agregas

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Notifications").child(post.getPublisher()).child(post.getNotifiid()).removeValue();
```

Comment: Tienes razón, lo he hecho ya lo del debugger y siempre se borra el último notifid. Podrías decirme cómo puedo hacer el query para obtener el valor específico para el post que quiero darle like?

Comment: Es que solo me da el ultimo valor para el notified y no se como obtener los otros. Hay alguna forma de asignarle una posición o algo para que sepa cuál quiero borrar y tal...

Comment: te esta dando el ultimo valor por que estas obteniendo mal del click en el viewholder el notifiid, fijate bien que del elemento que clicas te esta buscando otro id, o como cargas ese notifid

Comment: Fijate que cada vez que cargas una nueva notificacion haces esto, notifid = reference.push().getKey(); , entonces cada vez el valor de notifid va a ser el de la ultima notificacion puesta en tu base de datos

Comment: Lo que tenes que hacar es que en cada click de tu viewholder obtener ese valor del elemento que clicas notifid en vez de uar el valor global que estas guardando

Comment: Vale, pues hasta allí te sigo, pero es que no sé como cambiarlo para que busque el valor específico de que notifid si lo quiero borrar.

Comment: Ahi te edite la respuesta

Comment: Pero notifid no es algo que tengo en el Model class. Es algo que creo ahora en el momento cuando alguien pone un like en tu post o te deja un comentario... Entonces no sé cómo lo haría. Si fuera algo que tenía en el Post Model class sería fácil

Comment: Le tengo que asignar una posicion o algo, verdad?

Comment: es que deberias tenerlo en el model class por que cada vez que clicas deberias tenerlo junto a los datos de esa notificacion para poder borrar

Comment: Es justo lo que estaba pensando yo Tambien y lo tendría en plan solo para cuando necesite agrgear un método de mandar notificaciones, verdad?

Comment: Tío, sigo trabajando en este problema. Acabo de actualizar el código como lo tengo ahora. Puedes echarle un vistazo y decirme lo que estoy haciendo mal, porque sigue sin salir bien. Ahora cuando intento agregar la notificación se crean 50 mil notificaciones y tengo que parar Android Studio y borrarlo todo. Puedes decirme dónde está el fallo?

Comment: El mNotificationId lo he creado como un variable global para que luego a la hora de borar la notificación puedo hacer .child(mNotificationId).removeValue(); y en el método hago mNotificationId = notification.getNotificationId();

Comment: Lo que pasa es que cada vez que haces notifiid = red.push() estás creando una nueva clave y asignandole, por eso siempre tiene el valor de la última, no guarda el valor de cada notificación , sino siempre de la última, lo mismo va a pasar con mNotificationId , estás iterando por todo el nodo notificaciónes y si reescribiendo el valor de mNotificationId y siempre va a tener el valor del último

Comment: Estoy ahora intentando en lugar de hacerlo así como antes escribir un método para borrar la notificación. He probado hacerlo así, pero ahora se borran todas las notificaciones del usuario no solo la que yo quiero borra. Madremía

Comment: Si lo hago así que te parece... No me sale, pero así más limpio el código. me puedes decir por qué se están borrando todas las notificaciones del usuario en lugar de solo una la que quiero borrar? He actualizado el código, puedes echarle un vistazo?

Comment: pasame teamviewer te lo hago yo

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107257/discussion-between-johnnnn-and-gaston-saillen).